# How to increment variable defined at a Factory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-seeding, laravel-factory

I'm using Laravel 9 and I have made this Factory which inserts some data into a pivot table between `Question` && `Category` Models:

```
class CategoryQuestionFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        if(isset($counter)){
            $question = Question::find($counter);
        }else{
            $counter = 1;
            $question = Question::find($counter);
        }

        return [
            'category_id' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1,22),
            'question_id' => $question->id
        ];

        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Basically, the first time when this Factory runs, it will insert `question_id` of **1** and a random number between **1** & **22** as `category_id`.

But because I need to run this Factory more than one time (it should runs 50 times), I added this code to **`DatabaseSeeder.php`**:

```
public function run()
{
    for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
        (new CategoryQuestionFactory())->create();
    }
}
```

But because for the next times, I don't want to insert `question_id` of **1** again, I have defined a variable called `$counter` which increments at the end of function as well (to get the next record of question at *`questions`* table):

```
        if(isset($counter)){
            $question = Question::find($counter);
        }else{
            $counter = 1;
            $question = Question::find($counter);
        }

        return [
            ...
        ]

        $counter++;
```

But now the problem is, the value of `$counter` does not gets incremented and therefor, it inserts **1** for the all fifty times.

**So the question is**, how can I define a variable at Factory function, so the next time it runs the code, this variable is already incremented and no need to start from scratch.

---

### **UPDATE #1:**

[image]

---

### **UPDATE #2:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8 introduced new factory classes so your request can look like:

```
class CategoryQuestionFactory extends Factory {

    private static $questionId = 1;

    protected $model = Question::class;

    public function definition() {
         $question = Question::find(self::$questionId);

         self::$questionId++;
         return [
            'category_id' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1,22),
            'question_id' => $question->id
        ];

    }
```

And in you database seeder add the following

```
CategoryQuestion::factory()->times(50)->create();
```

Comment: It says **Unclosed '{' on line 11 at QuestionFactory.php:27**

Comment: I also added an **UPDATE** to the question

Comment: I tried that and again adds `question_id` of 1 for the all the records :(

Comment: I added **UPDATE #2** and `protected $model = Question::class;` must be changed to `protected $model = CategoryQuestion::class;`

Comment: You cannot run the factory like that!